# Why can't I parse a Ajax html GET response in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm tempering with a Chrome Extension where I use an Ajax-request to get HTML from a requested  URL. This works, but I want to get all the text values some certain elements. By example, everything with the class `.heading-bold` 
    **script.js**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://page.com/page.html",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
              console.log($(data).filter( '.heading_bold' ).text()); 
          }
    });
```

**Response HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head><title>Beerpong</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
    <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache" />
    </head>
     <body>
        <div id="table-container">
            <table>
               <tbody>
                  <tr>
                   <td><div class="heading_bold">Beerpong</div></td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Logging it to the console works just fine. This is my output:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0....
```

Why? Why won't it just console.log my desired values?

Comment: _Not_ the cause of the syntax error, but your selector would need to be `'.heading_bold'`, not `'#heading_bold'`.

Comment: @nnnnnn Typo, changed but still throws me the erorr: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <!DOCTYPE..."

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you are using jquery 1.9, do:

```
...
success: function(data) {
   var html = $.parseHTML(data); 
   console.log($(html).find( '.heading_bold' ).text()); 
}
..
```

Because as per [jQuery 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/):: HTML strings passed to jQuery() that start with something other than a less-than character will be interpreted as a selector. Since the string usually cannot be interpreted as a selector, the most likely result will be an "invalid selector syntax" error thrown by the Sizzle selector engine. Use jQuery.parseHTML() to parse arbitrary HTML.

Comment: Tried your snippet, now I am getting a empty output. And I have double-checked if the element exsist and if it's correct syntax. It should be, but just a empty output..

Comment: @Jack try using .find() instead of .filter()

Comment: what to do if I would like to count the parsed html by a class name like this `jQuery(html).find('.searchResultBox').length;`

Comment: @PlanetHackers yes, jQuery(html).find('.searchResultBox').length; will give you the count of elements having class name "searchResultBox".

Comment: @DemoUser I have tried this but returned result was 0. I solved this by using `.filter(...).length;`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to use "load" instead of "$.get()" if you want to insert a portion of the remote document into DOM.

```
$("#result").load("page.html .heading_bold",function(response){
console.log($(this).find(".heading_bold").val());           
});
```

Hope this is helpful to you.

Comment: It's a cross-domain requests, "load" wouldn't do the job.

Comment: $.ajax call still have cross-domain issue...right? Just curious... what strategy do you use to overcome the cross domain issue? CORS or Proxy?

Comment: I use a PHP proxy which tunnels through to the target