# how to read javascript variable from ajax success callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am doing

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: url, //valid url..The ajax part works fine
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {

        if (loginStatus !== 'false') {
            testFunction(response); //assuming there is a function called testFunction
        }
    }
});
```

The response is a mixed content of html and it also contains

```
<script>var loginStatus = 'false'</script>
```

if(loginStatus !== 'false') does not work in the success. What am I doing wrong?

The response looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
This is a test page
<script>var loginStatus = 'false'</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: share the response from ajax

Comment: @guradio -- just did

Comment: what does the target url actually contain?

Comment: `loginStatus !== 'false'` it means false !== false` ? it will never do your condition

Comment: @DavidJawphan-- that boolean gets set dynamically. So yes the idea is to evaluate that variable. If false dont call that method.

Comment: can you do `console.log($(response))` and show what it outputs in success

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is not pretty. This would be much easier if the response was JSON. [Why can't I parse a Ajax html GET response in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038544/why-cant-i-parse-a-ajax-html-get-response-in-jquery) provides hints to a potential solution.

You will have to parse the HTML that gets returned. The bad part is that the Javascript part will have to be `eval`d (bad practice!) unless you do some regular expression magic get the value of the variable.

**UPDATE (DON'T DO THIS):**

Again, disclaimer, **this is bad practice**, but it's possible. The following is just a proof of concept applied to your code. There is also a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aLkgnru9/7/) with the basic idea. Basically, you parse the response with JQuery's `.parseHTML` method and evaluate the script with `.globalEval` at which point the variable becomes available to check.

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: url, //valid url..The ajax part works fine
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function(response) {
    var scriptContent = $($.parseHTML(response, document, true)).filter('script').text();
    $.globalEval(scriptContent);
    // at this point, the variable loginStatus should be defined

    if (loginStatus !== 'false') {
        testFunction(response); //assuming there is a function called testFunction
    }
  }
});
```

Another reference: [jQuery - script tags in the HTML are parsed out by jQuery and not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699320/jquery-script-tags-in-the-html-are-parsed-out-by-jquery-and-not-executed)

Comment: yeah I wish I could though. I agree that would be a better solution

Comment: I update the answer with what I think is an example that *could* work. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I ended up listening to your first advise of not relying on eval and parsed that boolean as html like <span display="none" class="loginStatus">false</span>...then it became easy enough to do $(response).find('. loginStatus').html()..which worked

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't access a variable inside ajax return because its javascript is not interpreted.

It's not a good idea (and you could have others problems) but you can put the return to some hidden iframe and access the variable inside using something like:

```
document.getElementById("iframeId").contentWindow.loginStatus
```

If you have control of the page that you are retrieving the ajax result, I recommend you to response only the variable content or a json to manipulate easily in your javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'loginCheck.php', //valid url..The ajax part works fine
    dataType: 'html',
    success: function(response) {
        if (response == "YES") {
         testFunction(response); //assuming there is a function called testFunction
        }
    }
});
```

### loginCheck.php

// check the username and password
if it matches with the username and password in the database .
then echo "YES" otherwise echo "NO"

i explained this  login concept using PHP scripting language.